# Cloudant sync for couchdb; how to port android to J2SE

Tags: java, android, synchronization, cloudant

Am very interested in using cloudant's [new sync library](https://cloudant.com/blog/introducing-cloudant-sync/#.UxZIiOewJ-M) for iOS and Android.  However, I'd also like like comparable support for desktop via J2SE.  I realize this may be possible simply by bundling a local couchdb instance with your J2SE app & then using a wrapper like ektorp.  However, I would prefer something a little lighter - e.g. cloudant sync runs atop of a local SQLite db; rather than on top of local couchdb.

I've loaded the code into eclipse as a J2SE project however have about 40 errors to resolve; most of which are due to dependancies on android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.  Un suprisingly, copying the classes in question from the Android SDK didn't work.

I would appreciate any advice / pointers on a port, or alternative.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give us more details? Error dump, for starters...

Comment: the errors at the moment are all to do with SQLiteDatabase not being able to be resolved to a type; because its part of the android SDK.  Adding the android sdk class files to the project creates hundreds of new errors, as obviously there are fundamental differences between Dalvik VM and J2SE.

Comment: just to clarify, are you attempting to build cloudant-sync from source or use the pre-built jar?

Comment: Reece: how did you create the eclipse project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, as you discovered, while we choose the right data access class to use based on the runtime environment -- i.e., sqlite4java or the Android SQL classes -- the library requires the Android classes to be in the classpath even when running on a desktop.

We are hoping to address this with better dependency injection or build processes in the near future, and I'll try to keep this answer up to date.

Comment: Thanks! Seems I was almost there; just needed to include the whole android.jar (obtained form the android sdk) file in my build path.  Now it compiles.  Re: Will, I wasn't aware that there was a pre-built jar - hence I was compiling the source from github.

Comment: I'll post back / start a new thread if I run into runtime problems - thanks again.